# how to change the order of rows example project

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, struts2

An example code written in jsp/struts/servlet for the following problem.

I am struggling from many days on this topic. "Users can order the displayed rows".

I am displaying exercises in browser(tr,td tags) in ascending order , but i want to order each exercises according to my wish.(either drag/drop or by clicking some buttons).

And also when i logged out and then again login , then my exercise order should be same as i order it before.

Comment: as per your requirement, each use should see the way he/she has ordered the rows/ cloumn?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery sortable utility. Lets say you have a table like this:

```
<table>
   <tbody><tr>
       <td>Foobar1</td>
       </tr>   </tbody>
  <tbody><tr>
       <td>Foobar2</td>
    </tr> </tbody>
 <tbody><tr>
       <td>Foobar3</td>
    </tr> </tbody>
  <tbody><tr>
       <td>Foobar4</td>
    </tr> </tbody>
 <tbody><tr>
       <td>Foobar5</td>
    </tr>   </tbody>  
</table>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/aWFrK/

Then using jquery code you can activate the drag and drop functionality.

```
 $( "table" ).sortable();
```

More details can be found on http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Comment: yes sir, i used it in my page but if i refresh my page then the changed order is not remaining same.. i think i have to change something in my database. Please tell me in detail way like which extra field should i add in my database for that, or please send some example program for saving it in my database.

Comment: you can add `ordering` field in your database which should store the index of the row in the table (eg. the index of first TR is 0, so add 1 into it => 1). And fetch the rows to be displayed order by `ordering` using your sql query. There is a callback available to sortable utility which will let you save the ordering upon dropping any row or all at once (whichever preferable for you)

Comment: sir, please send 1 small example regarding this written in jsp/java.                       Email: ashutosh10g@gmail.com.

Comment: This might help you. 
http://forums.cibonfire.com/discussion/539/jquery-sortable-new-order-saved-to-database/p1

Comment: This is extremly good example (in php) but quite easy to implement it in jsp. 
http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/title/sort-table-rows-jquery.html

Comment: Sir, how can i write these 2 code into my jsp page. please convert it into java... (1).foreach($orders as $item) {$item = explode('=', $item);$item = explode('_', $item[1]);$array[] = $item[1]; (2).foreach($array as $key => $value) {$key = $key + 1;$sql = "UPDATE books SET order = ? WHERE id = ?";$objDb->prepare($sql)->execute(array($key, $value));}echo json_encode(array('error'=> false)); –